# Run a script before blank screen on shutdown/reboot

Tags: raspbian-buster, shutdown, reboot, plymouth, systemd-startup

I am trying to get my raspberry pi 3 (running Raspbian 10) to show an animation on boot and before shutdown/reboot.

using Plymouth I managed to get the boot animation, however, it doesn't display anything on reboot/shutdown. So I wrote a small shell script and linked it with systemd services to show the animation before shutdown.target reboot.target.

here is what I tried:

/etc/systemd/system/run2.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Run a script at shutdown
Before=multi-user.target

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

for the `Before=..` I also tried `Before=shutdown.target reboot.target` and `Before=plymouth.target`, they have the same result as explained above.

/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/test.sh :

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo plymouthd
sudo plymouth show-splash
sudo sleep 5
sudo touch /home/pi/Desktop/test
```

then:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/run2.service
sudo chmod +x  /lib/systemd/system-shutdown/test.sh


sudo systemctl enable run2.service
```

on each restart, the file `test` is created on the desktop but right after a `reboot` or `shutdown now` command but the screen goes blank without showing any animation.

can anybody give a newbie explanation on this subject?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service file looks good, except for the `Before=multi-user.target` line. That should be `After=multi-user.target`, because services get stopped in the inverted order they got started.

There's no need for `ExecStart=` or `Type=` as you can find the following in the manual pages:

> Type=oneshot is the implied default if neither Type= nor ExecStart= are specified.

and

> When Type=oneshot is used, zero or more commands may be specified.

To troubleshoot your problem add `exec &>> /var/log/run2.log` as the second line to your script and some `echo`s. This will redirect all output to a file (/var/log/run2.log) so that you can possibly see what has gotten wrong.

I tested it with following script

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &>> /home/pi/test.log
date
echo "shutdown"
sleep 2
echo "slept 2 seconds"
sleep 3
echo "slept another 3 seconds"
```

and after a reboot I found that `test.log` existed and contained:

```
Do 8. Aug 12:35:24 BST 2019 
shutdown
slept 2 seconds 
slept another 3 seconds
```

Comment: the problem turned out to be from another service which turned the screen power off to early (before execution of the script) to prevent that I executed 'sudo systemctl mask rpi-display-backlight.service' and called 'echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power' in the shell script to power off the lcd after the execution of the script.